# Router for RA, Linux for DHCPv6

Tags: ipv6, dhcp-server

I have a Mikrotik router. It has a DHCPv6 server, but it only gives out PD with it, it doesn't give out stateful addresses. I'd like to configure a Raspberry Pi (Debian) box for just the missing piece. I think I can disable the DHCPv6 server on the router and still send the DHCP flag in the RA.

Specifically, I'd like the Debian box to listen to RA from the router, and then serve DHCPv6 stateful addresses with same prefix out the same interface. I don't want to send RA from the Debian box, nor do I want to send DHCPv4. I'd love it if I could even create mac reservations.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I'm looking for a linux program and config that would hand out DHCPv6 addresses using a dynamic prefix it received via RA.

Comment: Huh? Mikrotik should have no problem doing stateful DHCPv6. There are plenty of guides and videos on setting it up. Come back with a specific problem if you actually have one. Your idea to use a separate DHCPv6 server won't really work, as you have no good way to pass the delegated prefix from upstream to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Mikrotik does not yet support handing out addresses with DHCPv6. This is mentioned several places in the Mikrotik forums, here's one link: https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=110892

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were after. I'm not familiar with how to separate these on RouterOS, and of course you still have the problem of passing along the delegated prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact details of your situation, but just to focus on your generic question: yes, the device sending the router advertisements and the device being the DHCPv6 server can definitely be separate devices.